# How can I save the name of a link between requests?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, jstl

I need to save a piece of data (which is a link) when I go from one page JSP to another one. Any help please?

for example, if I click on **AZE122** I want to display this in the second page (jsp) on which i'll be forwarded.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to save the link name between requests?

Comment: yup, that's it. But I need to put it as an attribute session.setAttribute("var", "test");

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: I have too many links and I need to memorize the one in which I click to display it in the second jsp page

Comment: use Map put values as corresponding to key such as `links.put("test","link url");`

Comment: but how do I know on which one I clicked before to get the second jsp page?

Comment: You would like to change the caption of your question. How can I memorize a link...well it depends on your capability to memorize. Simple way can be to write the link on a piece of paper 10 times, and possibility is that you memorize it in your mind. But if you want to memorize in your java program, you will need different ways which can be discussed separately. :)

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you everyone for your participation and your valuable suggestion. Here is a possible solution:

I just need to put these lines in the right **Servlet** or **JSP page**:

```
session.setAttribute("codeOperation", "AZE122");


request.getParameter("codeOperation");


<a href="<c:url value="/menu?rib=${ compte.rib }"/>">${ compte.rib }</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is difficult to understand what you using for you project but...
For example you have JSP page which render some HTML page but to get this JSP page you need some Java controller in back-end, am I right?

Lets imagine that you  have 2 JSP pages

1) Page 1  with URL www.yoursite.com/pages/firstpage

2) Page 2  with URL www.yoursite.com/pages/secondpage

Page 2 needs get URL www.yoursite.com/firstpage as a parameter

Step 1: JAVA back-end controller. We need it for return Page 1 and Page 2 for user when some one request one of existing URLs

Step 2: Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/pages")
@Controller
public class PageController {

    /**
     * Render first page.
     *
     * @param request some HTTP request.
     * @return string.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/firstpage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String renderFirstPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
         // some your code
         return "return model or whatever you need";
    }        

     /**
     * Render second page.
     *
     * @param request some HTTP request.         
     * @param parameters map with your url.
     * @return map.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/secondpage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> renderSecondPage(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> parameters) {
         String urlOfFirsPage = parameters.get("url").toString();
         Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
         model.put("url", urlOfFirsPage);
         return model;
    }


}
```

Method renderSecondPage() gets @RequestBody "parameters" that you sending for exmpl. with AJAX. Parameters contains field "url" that you can get from first JSP page. 
When controller hendels request for renderSecondPage() it can read "url" field from parameters and PUT to return model for JSP file of Page 2. 
In JSP(Page 2) you need only extract from model URL of first page.

That is what I got from your question. It really depends what you a using for rendering you views and getting request from front-end.

Comment: you can use the idea in my post. The code buggy and you need fix it =) but idea the same: (1)Create controller, (2)use Spring annotations for mapping, include URL what you need to JSON request from Page1 to Page2, (3) read URL from RequesBody and return it =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript. On onClick call a javascript function and set the value or id of the link to a var in javascript. Use this var to set in session.setAttribute("var", $var);. You can use the same using jsp method as well.